# Cross entropy error: Poor modelling giving too much weight to unlikely events

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, cross-entropy, divergence

I was reading this paper. [link](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf) (page 5)

In this paper, there is a statement that goes like this:

> To begin, cross entropy error is just one among many possible distance
> measures between probability distributions, and ***it has the unfortunate
> property that distributions with long tails are often modeled poorly
> with too much weight given to the unlikely events.***

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you give some more details & context of your application? Cross entropy is a machine learning term often describing logistic regression, so you (maybe) search for "rare event logistic regresion" or "robust logistic regression" or ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen.: There is no application from my side. I am just reading these papers to understand it. So that's why this question.